# Как передать неопределенное количество аргументов в функцию-конструктор при создании экземпляра?

Tags: javascript

Как более изящно сделать -

```
function Test( a, b ){
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
}

var test = new Test.call( ..., 1, 2 );
```

**Обновлено:**

```
function create( ){
    var type = arguments[0],
        length = arguments.length,
        args = [],
        instence = Object.create( type.prototype );

    while( length-- > 1 ){
        args[length - 1] = arguments[length];
    }

    return type.apply( instence, args );
}

create( Test, 2, 3 )
```

Comment: Ответ здесь http://stackoverflow.com/a/4116634  
Использовать arguments:

`var print_names = function() {
     for (var i=0; i<arguments.length; i++) console.log(arguments[i]);
}`

Comment: Вы уже задавали такой вопрос: http://hashcode.ru/questions/360120/javascript-new-constructor-apply-null-args-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE

Comment: @RubaXa: у меня часто возникало чувство, что подобное я уже спрашивал, но чтоб прям действительно, то это впервые:)  Приношу Вас извинить меня за... Когда я пытаюсь найти этому название, то получается, что это жуткое неуважение. Но уверяю, что это не так и скорее всего это усталость.  
И я наберусь наглости и спрошу у Вас - а вы не знаете, какие версии браузера НЕ поддерживают Object.create ? И есть ли замечания по поводу метода, который я добавил в вопрос?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно попробовать использовать apply вместо call, в apply передается массив аргументов вместо именованного списка. Либо, как вариант, передать объект:

```
var user = new userConstructor({
      age: 5,
      name: 'Vasya'
    });
```